# WPF MahApps HamburgerMenu SelectedIndex

Tags: wpf, selecteditem, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

I'm using MahApps HamburgerMenu control with HamburgerMenuIconItem items.
When I changing the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem property of HamburgerMenu, selected item is highlighted, but content of this item not showing.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the Selected Index, you must also change the content. You can do something like this:

```
HamburgermenuIconItem item = HamburgerMenuControl.Items[SelectedItems]    
HamburgerMenuControl.Content = item.Tag
```

However, unless you are doing something particular, i would stick with the classic event ItemClick instead of messing with the indexes

```
private void HamburgerMenuControl_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.HamburgerMenuControl.Content = e.ClickedItem;
        this.HamburgerMenuControl.IsPaneOpen = false;
    }
```

Note that HamburgerMenuControl is just the name i gave to the HamburgerMenu

Comment: @DanileSartori in your answer you cite `SelectedItems` as an indexer to `HamburgerMenuControl.Items`. Is that intentional or did you mean `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: @David Savage i don't remember honestly if you can change the SelectedItem property. However, i would stick with my suggestion to use item click event handler as in the second part of my answer